# Twilio "Twilio Voice Quickstart for Android" How to set 'callerId' dynamicly?

Tags: php, android, twilio-api, twilio-programmable-voice

I have download "Twilio Voice Quickstart for Android" Pre-Built App from [github](https://github.com/twilio/voice-quickstart-android#quickstart) .

In this apps set to number dynamicly

```
twiMLParams.put("to", contact.getText().toString());
```

And on server php code get to number

```
$to = isset($_POST["to"]) ? $_POST["to"] : "";
if (!isset($to) || empty($to)) {
  $to = isset($_GET["to"]) ? $_GET["to"] : "";
}
```

And callerNumber is static

```
$callerNumber = '1234567890';
```

I want to set callerNumber (callerId) dynamicly from my apps . Is it possible ?

Thank's

Answer (score 0):

Well not sure. But you can try this.

Try sending your callerID with the receiverID like this

```
twiMLParams.put("to", contact.getText().toString()+","+callerId);
```

In the server side just explode the `$to` veriable.

```
$to = isset($_GET["to"]) ? $_GET["to"] : "";
$toFrom = explode(",", $to);
$to = $toFrom[0];
$from = $toFrom[1];
```

Hope that will solve your problem.

Comment: Nice idea . Thanks  :)